# Reinforcement Learning: Plotting timsteps vs rewards

Tags: python, machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

I am fairly new to Machine Learning and have been working on PPO2 for Reinforcement Learning via stable baselines for Python.

The code that you need to know is:

```
env = gym.make('fishing-v0')
model = PPO2(MlpPolicy, env , verbose=2)

obs = env.reset()
for i in range(100):
  action, _states = model.predict(obs)
  obs, rewards, dones, info = env.step(action)
  env.render()
  
env.close()
```

How Would I make a plot of the number of timesteps as the x axis, and the reward as the y axis

I have tried:

```
def step():
  obs = env.reset()
  for i in range(100):
    action, _states = loaded_model.predict(obs)
    obs, rewards, dones, info = env.step(action)
    while i <= 100:
      x = []
      x.append(i)
      i += 1
      return x
    env.render()

step()

y = rewards
plt.figure(figsize=(9, 4))
plt.plot(x, y, linewidth=2.0)
plt.show()
```

But I get just a blank x and y axis, here:

[plot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DVXv.png)

Thanks

Comment: It should be while I <=100:       And while loop is infinite loop in your case, no increment of I inside while loop

Comment: @BabanGain Sorry about that silly mistake, but now after I correct it, the code block keeps running and does output anything. I was wondering about this.

Comment: I have tried this                                                                    `                                                                                                    
def step():
  obs = env.reset()
  for i in range(100):
    action, _states = loaded_model.predict(obs)
    obs, rewards, dones, info = env.step(action)
    while i <= 100:
      x = []
      x.append(i)
      i += 1
      return x
    env.render()

step()

y = rewards
plt.figure(figsize=(9, 4))
plt.plot(x, y, linewidth=2.0)
plt.show()
  ` but I still get a blank axis

Comment: Sorry  I can't help in this matter

Comment: Would you like to have a plot which updates after say 100 timesteps or do you just want the final plot of rewards vs steps?

Comment: @nsidn98. I would like to have plot that updates every 100 timesteps. Thanks